# In jenkins job for Spring project, inject a variable in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jenkins

I am trying to create three different jenkins jobs for a single code base.
The only change in  three projects I want 
is
   `<property name="locations"><list>
   <value>file:${EXTERNAL_PROPERTIES_DIR}/Proj${version}.properties</value>
                </list>
</property>`

So, I want three projects which use three different properties Proj1.properties, Proj2.properties, Proj3.properties.

Now, my question is, how can I pass this ${version} variable dynamically from jenkins job?

Comment: Add an var in your Jenkins Job.

Comment: how can I use it in xml?

Comment: https://www.qwant.com/?q=jenkins%20maven%20var&t=all